# Oracle 19c Client Installation Stuck/freezes error: INFO: Checking whether the IP address of the localhost could be determined. suspecting GP Policy

Tags: oracle19c

I am trying to install Oracle Client 19c when i starts the installation its freezes at stage 1, checked logs it hangs on "INFO: Checking whether the IP address of the localhost could be determined...", i refer some article to skip stage mentioned step but it also stuck on stage 7.

My System is in Domain

I tried the installation on recently formatted System and it worked with antivirus.
also tried to disable the Antivirus from my system but faced the same freezing issues. if unjoin the Domain and try it works.

I suspect the issue with any Domain Policy but dont understand the which policy is creating the problem, please suggest the solution.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are seeing "Reading from the pipe"  message in ...\Inventory\logs  OUT files then, login Windows with an admin account and run the services called "Server" and "Workstation".